# Search using words in any order or combination and return row

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My table has a row that is stored as `D1234 HEX SCREW GS0090 O109`. Currently I can do something like this `D1234 HEX` or `SCREW GS0090` and it will return the row. However I want to be able to enter words in any combination or any order like `D1234 GS0090`or `HEX D1234` and have it return this row. How can this be done?

Edit: I'm using Laravel 5.4, a mysql database which uses the MyISAM engine

```
$products = DB::connection('it')
            ->table('it')
            ->join('units','units.code', '=', 's.code')
            ->join('vendors', 'vendors.code', '=', 's.code')
            ->where('s.deleted', '=', 0)
            ->where('vendors.deleted', '=', 0)
            ->where('s.description', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
            ->orWhere('s.vendorcode', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%' )
            ->orWhere('s.vendordefaultcode','LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
            ->orWhere('vendors.partnumber', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
            ->orWhere('vendors.partvendorcode', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
            ->get());
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using full text search if you are using mysql. It is mainly used for advanced searching, but it enhances your search very well.

First you will need to add a `fulltext` index to the table for each column you want to use full text search:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD FULLTEXT(description);
```

Next modify your query:

```
$products = DB::connection('it')
            ->table('it')
            ->join('units','units.code', '=', 's.code')
            ->join('vendors', 'vendors.code', '=', 's.code')
            ->where('s.deleted', '=', 0)
            ->where('vendors.deleted', '=', 0)
            ->whereRaw("MATCH (s.description) AGAINST ('{$term}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
            ->orWhereRaw("MATCH (s.vendorcode) AGAINST ('{$term}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
            ->orWhereRaw("MATCH (s.vendordefaultcode) AGAINST ('{$term}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
            ->orWhereRaw("MATCH (vendors.partnumber) AGAINST ('{$term}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
            ->orWhereRaw("MATCH (vendors.partvendorcode) AGAINST ('{$term}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
            ->get());
```

Some links to help out

[MySQL Full-Text Search with Multiple words](http://www.vionblog.com/mysql-full-text-search-with-multiple-words/)

[mySQL Full Text Search With Percentage Scoring](http://blog.oneiroi.co.uk/mysql/php/mysql-full-text-search-with-percentage-scoring/)

Comment: The only problem with this is if I enter `D1234 HEX` it'll return everything with `D1234` and `HEX` I only want rows with both `D1234 HEX` returned

Comment: Actually I think its returning all rows with the first word i.e. `D1234`